# How to delete the current cell in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I delete a current cell in a DataGridView. I am trying the code below, but it is deleting all cells except the current one.

```
private void dgvPurchase_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < datagridview.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            datagridview.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value="";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following link describe how to achive what you want ,
Please check the link , I am sure that will help you ,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yc4fsbf5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you do deleting cell value in CellValidating Event ..

To delete value in CurrentCell .. you may try

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not %100 sure but you can use [`DataGridView.CurrentCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property like;

```
int yourcolumnIndex = datagridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int yourrowIndex = datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

datagridview.Rows[yourrowIndex ].Cells[yourcolumnIndex].Value="";
```

Or even using [`DataGrid.CurrentCellChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.currentcellchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event could be better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
DataGridName.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridName.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
```

Comment: Don't just paste code as an answer, it will be good if you can explain it.